# python wx / py2exe error

Tags: wxpython, py2exe, wxwidgets

I wrote a tool in python in which I import the wxpython libraries.
I then convert the tool to an .exe file with py2exe.
Everything works as expected and the executable gets created.

When I launch the executable it crashes and this message is written in the log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "v2.py", line 1, in <module>
File "wx\__init__.pyc", line 45, in <module>
File "wx\_core.pyc", line 16641, in <module>
AssertionError: wxPython/wxWidgets version mismatch
```

Any suggestion?
Thanks
AC

Comment: note that I am using python scripter in a PortableApps installation of python under windows and I installed wxpython via easyinstall.

Answer (score 0):

solution: remove ./dist and ./build folders, then run your py2exe script again.